# Warning SQL04151: Trigger has an unresolved reference to object

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I came across an issue building my database project in VS 2010 Ultimate. I have imported database objects and settings from an existing database (previously created using SSMS 2008 r2 which is all correct). There were a bunch (21) of similar warnings and one error which I fixed adding `master.dbschema` reference. But even after that some warnings continue to be shown on project build. Namely, I get this warning:

```
Warning SQL04151: Trigger: [dbo].[TIMESHEET_TRGR] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[TIMESHEET_HSTR_TBL]
```

and simillar ones one per every column in the `TIMESHEET_HSTR_TBL` table that is used in the trigger (the `ID` column which is auto generated `IDENTITY` isn't used):

```
Warning SQL04151: Trigger: [dbo].[TIMESHEET_TRGR] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[TIMESHEET_HSTR_TBL].[MODIFICATION_TIME].
Warning SQL04151: Trigger: [dbo].[TIMESHEET_TRGR] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[TIMESHEET_HSTR_TBL].[OPERATION_TYPE].
```

and so forth.

As you can see the trigger and the table are in the same schema and they are also in the same database. Any help how to fix (not suppress) these warnings would be really appreciated.

Comment: Without more information, I would be guessing that the trigger is being created before the table "timesheet_hstr_tbl" is created.  So if  the create trigger statements are moved to the bottom of the script, these errors would be fixed.